# How can i toggle link color using jquery

Tags: jquery

For example, if i have a drop down navigation, i would like the active link to have a different color than the rest of the navigation link.Something similar to: http://www.emerson.edu/.

Here is my jquery code:

```
if ($(".testHeader a#" + thisID).hasClass("active")) {
    $(".testHeader a").removeClass("active");
} else {
    $(".testHeader a").removeClass("active");
    $(".testHeader a#" + thisID).addClass("active");
}
```

Where my `active` class is a css style that changes the link color.

The problem that i am having is that each link is staying active if i click more than 1 link. I actually want only want one link to be active when being clicked. What is wrong my jquery? Thanks!

Comment: would really help to know "when" this if statement fires. Could give you several different answers otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You can just say

```
$(".testHeader a#"+thisID).toggleClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`. First remove all the active classes when the event is triggered and then add the class on to the currently selected object, `this`.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**EDIT**: To close it by clicking again, do this.

```
$('a').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('active')){
         $(this).removeClass('active');
     }else{
         $('a').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
     }

});
```

Comment: This works but the link is still active when the menu closes.

Comment: What action and event are you using to close the menu?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what "event" this takes place on.

If it is a `hover` event. Then you could do something like:

```
$('.testHeader a').hover(function(e) { $(this).toggleClass('active'); });

//  However, if any of your links are dynamic or a half dozen other issues, this could misfire
//  Thus I would really suggest the long form as:

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.testHeader a', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
.on('mouseleave', '.testHeader a', function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
})
```

If on `click` event then you could do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.testHeader a', function(e) {
    $('.testHeader .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```